# Is there a limit for Redisearch ft.mget command for number of doc ids in a single query?

Tags: redisearch

I would want to pass maybe tens of thousands of document ids to ft.mget command, or even more - possibly even hundreds of thousands. Is this supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only limit is the number of argument in a redis command which is 1M if I remember correctly.